# How to show whether client-side javascript files matches the version in source control?

Tags: javascript, security, version-control

In the case of a web application, is there a way of showing the user that the client-side code running in their browser is the same version as the source code?

This is important in terms of security to show that client-side javascript hasn't been replaced by potentially malicious code in the deploy process.

Comment: You mean by running a `diff`? Just get something like GitExtensions, SourceTree, BeyondCompare, KDiff, WinMerge, etc?

Comment: Yes a diff would work for technical users, however non-technical users probably won't want to go through this process. I was looking for a way to demonstrate the versions match for non-technical users

Comment: So essentially you're asking if you can confirm that a **visitor** to your site has the same JavaScript as you're serving on the site? Wouldn't that always be the case, considering they download a copy **from** the site?

Comment: Yeap exactly! It may not necessarily the case since the website can be modified before deployment.

Comment: Hmm. I think the best you can do is check whether the page is [**loaded from the cache**](http://monket.net/blog/articles/detecting-when-a-page-is-loaded-from-the-browser-cache/). You could also check out Microsoft's [**Code Deployment Integrity Policies**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/device-security/device-guard/deploy-code-integrity-policies-steps), which might be able to offer some tips on deploying securely.